# rosbag API C++: Message Header Stamp sec and nsec are always zero?

Tags: ros, rosbag, timestamp, header

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The "sec" and "nsec" values in the message header are always zero when recording using "rosbag::write".  I provide a valid Time for the second parameter, but that only seems to affect the message body timestamp and playback timing, but not the header.  Is that expected?

I am converting some odometry and depth image information that was collected in Windows to a rosbag containing tf, depth_image, and camera_info messages (using rosbag API in C++)for consumption by the slam_gmapping node.

The rosbag I create looks correct and it plays back OK (correct timing) but the map is not generated.  I looked at the code, and the slam_gmapping node is using a tf::MessageFilter.  When I turn on DEBUG messages, I see messages like this "`MessageFilter [target=/odom]: Added message in frame camera_depth_frame at time 0.000`".  The message queue fills up with messages with time `0.0000`.   When I inspect my bag with rqt_bag the header.sec and header.nsec are always zero, so I thought maybe that is the issue.

I have called "rosparam set use_sim_time true", but that does not help.  Why is the header stamp always zero, and is that what is causing the tf::MessageFilter to never synch?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/123096/rosbag-api-c++:-message-header-stamp-sec-and-nsec-are-always-zero?/) by [gershon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4399/gershon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2014-01-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured out how to set the header.
It is the geometry_msgs::TransformStamped that has a .header and .stamp... not the tf::tfMessage (which is a list of geometry_msgs)

-G

---

Originally posted by [gershon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4399/gershon/) with karma: 73 on 2014-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1